# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list while writing to file

Tags: python, regex, file, file-io, readlines

I wrote one program which help inrementing the digit in the file.
 Able to copy **only first** line if I am using **writelines** and for f.write I am getting
    f.write(new_line ) if lines[0].strip().endswith(':') else f.write([new_line, *lines])
    TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list

```
file.txt

Django 2.1:0
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
```

My Code

```
import re
regex = r'(?<=:)\d*$'
def incr_patch_version(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        #print  (lines[0])
        new_line = re.sub(regex, lambda x: str(int(x.group()) + 1 if x.group().isnumeric() else 0), lines[0])
        f.seek(0)
        print (*lines)
        f.write(new_line ) if lines[0].strip().endswith(':') else f.write([new_line, *lines])
        #f.write(new_line ) if lines[0].strip().endswith(':') else f.writelines([new_line, *lines])
fname = 'file.txt'
incr_patch_version(fname)
```

if I am using  f.write(new_line ) if lines[0].strip().endswith(':') else f.writelines([new_line, *lines]). I am getting the below output

```
Django 2.1:3
Django 2.1:2
Django 2.1:1
Django 2.1:0
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
```

Desired Output file after 2 execution

```
Django 2.1:2
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2        
Django 2.1:1
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2        
Django 2.1:0
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
```

Comment: Using ternary `a if c else b` as a statement, instead of as an expression, while valid, is probably not very good style... if at all, use the ternary for the parameters only, within the `(...)`

Comment: Your __real__ issue is not with `write()` refusing a list (which obviously won't work - if you want to write a list of strings, `wtitelines()` is the proper method), but with using a wrong algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update you code like below

```py
import re
import os

regex = r'(?<=:)\d*$'


def incr_patch_version(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

        i = 1

        while i < len(lines)and ":" not in lines[i]:
            i += 1

        new_line = re.sub(regex, lambda x: str(int(x.group()) + 1 if x.group().isnumeric() else 0), lines[0])

        if not lines[i-1].endswith(os.linesep):
            lines[i-1] += os.linesep

        f.seek(0)
        new_lines = [new_line, *lines[1:i], *lines]
        f.writelines(new_lines)
        print(*new_lines)


fname = 'file.txt'
incr_patch_version(fname)
```

And the output in the file is like below

```
Django 2.1:4
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
Django 2.1:3
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
Django 2.1:2
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
Django 2.1:1
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
Django 2.1:0
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
```

Comment: would you mind telling me name = lines[1] if lines[1].endswith(os.linesep) else lines[1] + os.linesep

Comment: So basically if you have just one entry in file and the last line has no line ending then we want to add a new line while considering the last line. This will only happen when the file has 2 lines and last line doesn't end with a new line

Comment: In the above case you done, instead of name variable, we can add do print  also. So i have updated the file.txt

Comment: Sure will fix it, but next time please add the final case in your question first

Answer (score 1):

Your actual issue is here :

```
else f.write([new_line, *lines])
```

As you can see, you're giving a list as input to `write` method.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach.

```
import re
first_chunk = False
chunk = ""
with open(filename) as infile:
    content = infile.read()              #Read Content
    for line in content.splitlines():    #Iterate Lines
        match = re.match("\w+", line)    #Check for lable
        if match and first_chunk:        #Break if lable chunk found
            break
        elif match:
            first_chunk = True
            pattern = re.compile(r":(\d+)")
            chunk += pattern.sub(":{}".format(int(pattern.search(line).group(1))+ 1) ,  line)    #Increment count
        else:
            chunk += "\n" + line

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:            #Write back to file
    result = "{}\n{}".format(chunk, content)
    outfile.write(result)
```

**Output:**

```
Django 2.1:3
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
Django 2.1:2
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
Django 2.1:1
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
Django 2.1:0
    djangoAPI1
    djangoAPI2
```

Comment: How you wrote ? How you put into logic into code :)

Comment: Sorry i do not understand